# Meaning of a sentence from The Diary of a Young Girl? And what was ‘shall’ used for?

Tags: sentence-meaning, conjunctions, will-shall

I would like to ask you a couple of questions about the sentence below which is from **The Diary of a Young Girl**.

> I hope I shall be able to confide in you completely,
>
> *as I have never been able to do in anyone before,*
>
> and I hope that you will be a great support and comfort to me.

Q1) What meaning does the conjunction `as` hold there? So eventually what does the second line mean in relation to first line?

Q2) And why was `shall` used in the first line instead of `will`?
What difference does it make?

Comment: Remember that Anne Frank wrote in Dutch, not English. So this could also be a translator's choice to render the original words in a way that retains some of the flavor of the original language.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, thank you for the advice. But anyway,  how does the second line influence the meaning of the whole sentence? Does that mean that she hopes that she can confide in the diary to such a degree that she has never been able to experience before? Or does that just mean that she has not been able to confide in anyone before? What is the nuance of the second line?

Comment: I think Stoney's answer covers it. She hopes she will be able to confide in her diary more completely than she ever has in a person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Technically, *as* is the preposition which introduces the back half of a comparative construction, with the front half suppressed because it's basically irrelevant.<sup>†</sup> In this instance you might think of it as a *such ... as ...* construction:

> ... *in such a way* as I have never been able to *confide in anyone [in that way]* before ...

In effect, it's a way of adding a second, parenthetical clause to the sentence:

> I hope I shall be able to confide in you completely
>    (I have never been able to confide in anyone in that way before)
>    and I hope that you will be a great support and comfort to me.

Q2: In the 18th and 19th centuries (and among schoolteachers well into the 20th century) the *prestige* dialects of England and employed *shall* for *will* in the first person. Probably you can safely ignore this, unless English examiners in your country are at least fifty years out of date.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>I must tell you that the *Cambridge Grammar* says this is the **front** half of the construction; but I find their explanation of this impenetrable.</sub>

Comment: But if I may, I would like to more concretely know about the nuance of the meaning of the second line in the sentence. And the reason why I asked about `as` is that I thought `as` looked like it held the key. So, does that mean the writer wants to confide in the diary to an extreme extent that she never experienced before?

Comment: @SmartHumanism More or less, though I would not necessarily characterize this as "extreme". She feels she may speak unreservedly, which she has never been able to do before.

Comment: So, does she want the diary become something she confides in more intensely than anything before, or does she need the diary to become something she can confides in because she has never had anyone to fully confide in?

Comment: And is there a nuance that the degree that she wants to confide in the diary is considerable or is no degree implied?

Comment: @SmartHumanism No degree is *implied*--it is explicitly stated: *completely*. She hopes she will be able to confide in the diary to that degree and implies that it is through filling that role that the diary will be a great help and support.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you continuously, but would you give an explanation focusing on this? On whether she wants the diary become something she confides in more intensely than anything before, or she needs the diary to become something she can confides in because she has never had anyone to fully confide in. Why I keep asking this is to identify the nuance of `as` there. Thank you so much, StonyB.

Comment: @SmartHumanism In some cases *as* puts forward a causal relationship, but it does not do so in this case:  Anne says merely that she *hopes* that she will be able to do something she has never been able to do before. She doesn't address *why* she wants or needs to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer again. This one more question can feel like a repetition and you could be bothered. But to get to the final answer I have to ask this to you. I really appreciate your continuous help. Is there a manner the degree that she hopes to do confides in the diary to is more intense than she has ever confided in anyone before? I would like to know if `as` has a nuance of relative comparaison of the degree.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Her statement addresses the degree of *completeness* but not the degree of *intensity*--she says in effect that she can say *everything* but gives no indication how much emotion will lie behind that. This does not prevent you from inferring that she will write with intense emotion, but she does not actually say that.

Comment: Wow, I used the word 'intense' so wrongly. I meant 'more completely' instead of 'more intense'. Sorry for that. Would you give an answer to my last comment with this fix reflected?

Comment: @SmartHumanism Ah, I see! I wondered where you were getting *intense* from! ... Yes: there is a comparison, and you may say that it is a comparison of degree of completeness--though some authorities would protest that *complete* is binary, something is either complete or it's not. But what sets the journal apart from those she has confided in before is that she hopes to confide **completely** in the journal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the continuous answers! I am pestering you, I think. Even though I might be obsessed with this so much, I really feel the need to ask this more. In your last comment(which is just right above) you said there is a comparison. But what I focus on is the comparison implied by the conjunction "as" there.